# How to Add Content Page to Segment Control in IOS Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uisegmentedcontrol

I have used Segmented Control in my application. I don't know how to add two content pages to Segment control like a tabbed page. I have attached the sample file. Please give any suggestion [Link for Sample Application](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-lCg-rQFFH7V8fZKPFyFoPaAJWoamwVU)

Sample Code:

```
public partial class SamplePage : ContentPage
{

    SegmentedControl segControl;
    SegmentedControlOption optionOne;
    SegmentedControlOption optionTwo;

    public SamplePage()
    {
        segControl = new SegmentedControl();
        optionOne = new SegmentedControlOption();
        optionTwo = new SegmentedControlOption();            

        optionOne.Text = "One";
        optionTwo.Text = "Two";                  

        segControl.Children.Add(optionOne);
        segControl.Children.Add(optionTwo);

        var stack = new StackLayout()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Children = { segControl }
        };

        this.Content = stack;

    }       
}
```

[ScreenShot Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEqet.png)

Comment: Include the relevant code directly in your question, not as an external link.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some suggestions and explanations.

1. We can't put a `ContentPage` inside another `ContentPage`

   It's better to use `ContentView` instead of `ContentPage`
2. `Grid` is more recommended in this scenario , since it fills with the whole Screen.
3. Use `ValueChanged` event to change the view dynamically.

#### Code :

*Page*

```
public partial class SegmentedAppPage : ContentPage
{
    SegmentedControl segControl;      
    SegmentedControlOption scOptionOne;
    SegmentedControlOption scOptionTwo;

    Grid grid;

    View1 view1 = new View1();
    View2 view2 = new View2();

    public SegmentedAppPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        segControl = new SegmentedControl();
        segControl.SelectedValue = "One";
        scOptionOne = new SegmentedControlOption();
        scOptionTwo = new SegmentedControlOption();            

        scOptionOne.Text = "One";
        scOptionTwo.Text = "Two";

        segControl.Children.Add(scOptionOne);
        segControl.Children.Add(scOptionTwo);

        grid = new Grid();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        grid.Children.Add(segControl, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(view1, 0, 1);

        this.Content = grid;

        segControl.ValueChanged += SegControl_ValueChanged;
    }

    private void SegControl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SegmentedControl control = sender as SegmentedControl;
        if(control.SelectedValue is "One")
        {
            grid.Children.Remove(view2);
            grid.Children.Add(view1,0,1);  //This line 
        }
        else if (control.SelectedValue is "Two")
        {
            grid.Children.Remove(view1);
            grid.Children.Add(view2, 0, 1); //This line 
        }
        this.Content = grid;
    }
}
```

*ContentView*

```
public class View1 : ContentView
{
    public View1()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "View1" }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*To set default value on segmentedControl , modify code in `SegmentedControlRenderers`*

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedControl> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    var segmentedControl = new UISegmentedControl();

    for (var i = 0; i < e.NewElement.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        segmentedControl.InsertSegment(e.NewElement.Children[i].Text, i, false);
    }

    segmentedControl.ValueChanged += (sender, eventArgs) => {
        e.NewElement.SelectedValue = segmentedControl.TitleAt(segmentedControl.SelectedSegment);
    };
    segmentedControl.SelectedSegment = 0; // add this line
    SetNativeControl(segmentedControl);
}
```

#### Test

[image]

Comment: Hi,

At the page appearing View1 and View2 is working fine. but I click  "One" from "Two" the View2 and View1 text are overrided.I have attached the screenshot now.

Comment: Do you copy completely my code ?  Check this line : `grid.Children.Remove(view2);`

Comment: I have copied the code fully.still I can't figure out my mistake.

Comment: sorry , my mistake, I have changed the code in method `SegControl_ValueChanged` , please check it ..