# Segment Control Width is not setting in IOS Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I used Segment Control renderer in my application. When I set widthrequest to segment control it is not changing. My Segment control is like attached sample application, 
[How to Add Content Page to Segment Control in IOS Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631238/how-to-add-content-page-to-segment-control-in-ios-xamarin-forms)

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849565/understanding-widthrequest

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below line in my custom renderer it will work fine.

```
 segmentedControl.SetWidth(150.0f, 0);
 segmentedControl.SetWidth(150.0f, 1);
```